# [moveIt] Prevent motions through unknown areas?

Tags: moveit, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I was just wondering if there is a feature implemented into MoveIt, that prevents the robot from going through unknown areas? My 3D-Camera feeds the DepthImageOctomapUpdater plugin, which as far as I know differentiates between "empty" "full" and "unknown", so in theory it should be possible, right?

Thanks in advance,

Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197071/%5Bmoveit%5D-prevent-motions-through-unknown-areas?/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the MoveIt-Concepts it is possible to do that via the "Visibility Constraints":

http://moveit.ros.org/documentation/concepts/#Motion_Planning

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1